Returns an error when trying to change the touchpad scroll speed on Ubuntu 24.04
sudo xinput set-prop 'MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Touchpad' 'libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default' 40

I have already changed the scrolling speed with this command before. But I recently reinstalled the OS and now when I want to change the scroll speed again, I get an error:
Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)

Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)

Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()

Serial number of failed request:  21

Current serial number in output stream:  22

How can I solve this problem?
